# Cannot retrieve image from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I want to retrieve images (in binary format) from my SQL Server database on a button click. But when I click on the button an error occurs:

> System.InvalidOperationException {"Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."}

Code:

```
 private void onSearchClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand cmdSelect;
        SqlDataReader reader;

        string connStr =     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["house"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

        String strSelect = "Select FoodName, Images From Food where FoodName = @foodName";
        cmdSelect = new SqlCommand(strSelect, conn);
        cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foodname", comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        conn.Open(); 
        reader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();

        //retrieve image
        byte[]blob = (byte[])reader["Images"];
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        stream.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
        stream.Position = 0;
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        ms.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);
        bi.StreamSource = ms;
        bi.EndInit();
        image6.Source = bi;

        try {                             
            while (reader.Read()) {
                String nameOfFood = reader["FoodName"].ToString();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: On what line does the error happen?

Comment: p/s on the byte[]blob = (byte[])reader["Images"]; line

Comment: it says System.InvalidOperationException {"Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."}

Comment: while I have data in my database

Comment: are you saving image in db in base64 or BLOB?

Comment: I am using varBinary in my database

Comment: You really should be using `using` statements to close your connection (and the command, reader, image, and memory stream too. Anything that implments `IDisposeable` you are expected to either wrap in a `using` or have `Dispose()` eventually called on it). If a exception gets thrown anywhere in your code you will not close the connection.

Comment: You are missing a call to `reader.Read()` between `reader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();` and the "retrieve image" line (required to actually advance the reader to the first row). That's your immediate problem at least. I wouldn't be surprised if more issues surface down the track though - you should really look at tidying up that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after

```
reader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();
```

you have to call

```
reader.Read();
```

for reading 1st row from db.
Even better

```
if (reader.Read())
{
  //query returns some data and you may get image from reader fields
}
```

Comment: yes u are right, why have I not thought about it, thks for your help, really appreciate it thks.